# Code to input information from textbox to database tables

Tags: database, vb.net

Hope you will be able to help me.

Basically I built a form on an separate windows form on VB 2008 and this form contains textboxes where I want to put information and then when I click save it will transfer this info to the tables of the database I've already created.

Can someone help please.

Many thanks
Mark

Comment: This is way too broad. You're not stating a lot of details. What DB will you be using? What have you tried? You really don't expect us to show you how to develop a database application, do you? There are many tutorials that can help you out in starting out on this task. Then you can come back with specific problems when you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

in your click to save method

```
dim Value as string = textboxInForm.text
dim con as SqlConnection = new SqlConnection("My connection string ")
dim cmd as SqlCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tableName (Col1) VALUES('" & Value & "')",con)
cmd = cmd.ExecuteNonQUery
```

hope that helps